# How to extract flash video from a Mac app?

Tags: adobe-flash

I have a tutorial CD-ROM that consists of flash videos presented in a standalone player. I'd like to "rip" them to my computer so that I can play them without the CD-ROM itself, and without the standalone player entirely.  I'd like to be able to play each flash movie individually, and even copy only the specific ones I want to take with me. This means that simply making an ISO image of the CD-ROM, is also not sufficient.

I can't seem to find the media files themselves. Opening the .app's package contents, has shown me nothing but a flash player and various localization files. How can I copy out the media files themselves, other than screen-capturing them while they play back in realtime?

Please note:  I'm not looking for information on how to download flash files from a website. This has nothing to do with any web page, this is specifically about extracting flash files from a standalone, self-contained player application.

Comment: What else is on the CD-ROM besides the Application? Flash files typically end in .swf or .flv, searching the whole CD-ROM might locate them somewhere.

Comment: What assures you the videos are Flash encoded? The tutorial could be using Flash to play video encoded in another use Finder to list all files on the CD larger than a few megabytes (or another size appropriate to the video clips). The CD author might be using a different file extension on the media files to make this type of "finding" more difficult.

Comment: Can you view the videos offline? Are you sure they're in-app/on-disk at all?

Comment: There are no swf or flv files on the disk at all.  I couldn't even find any in the package contents.  The only thing on the CD, is a single Application.  Launching it presents a Flash Player that loads up video content, and allows for navigating among the tutorials.  Not sure what else to do since there aren't any other files other than a single readme document.

Comment: Running ‘find /Volumes/NAME-OF-CD -print‘ in Terminal will give you a list of all accessible content.

Comment: BINGO!!!  That was exactly what I needed, and I have found ALL of the .flv files!  Thanks you so much @patrix!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User @patrix gave this suggestion which turned out to be exactly what I needed:  `Running ‘find /Volumes/NAME-OF-CD -print‘ in Terminal will give you a list of all accessible content.`

Answer (score 2):

You can use File Juicer. It is a very good program. I am using it since 2005. It works flawlessly. It will extract audio, video, doc, flash everything and keep them in separate folders.

http://echoone.com/filejuicer/

Comment: Quite an intriguing suggestion!  Even though I don't want to pay for an app for this, I was curious enough to check FileJuicer out.  Unfortunately all it found were icons, some small .tiff files, a few text files, and 3 very small swf files that are not the movies.  Bummer, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score -3):

There are quite a few apps for this. Here's [one](http://mac.sothink.com) and here's [another](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/24405/videobox)

Comment: perhaps not Videobox. that seems more for online videos

Comment: So here is another idea: http://www.flash-decompiler.com/mac.html

Comment: As long as he doesn't have the Flash files, any decompiler won't help.

Comment: Totally not what I'm looking for, this has nothing at all to do with downloading flash files from the internet.

Comment: I understand that. Did you look at any of the products. They have free trials, and may find the files on your cd.

Comment: As far as I can tell, they all expect to decompile a swf file into something else.  I don't even *have* a swf file to work from.  I have a .app and that's all, plus this isn't important enough to me to justify paying for a tool even if it would do the trick.